# Understanding Ok with error propagation operator?

Tags: rust

I've seen this pattern on more than one occasion:

```
fn f() -> Result<..., ...> {
   ...
   Ok(expression()?)
}
```

Specifically, I find the order `Ok(expression()?)` confusing. What's the return type of `expression()?` and is there an interplay between `Ok` and this type? It seems, the function `Ok` must do more than just capturing the value. But how can it force a return with an error, if it's the last expression wrapping the return type of `expression()?`.

Comment: `Ok(x)` is not a function, it's a construction of variant `Ok` from enum `Result` with inner value of `x`.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, I got this far https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/try.rs.html#32, but it still doesn't help me much to understand the magic behind `Ok + ?`. Any pointers?

Comment: AFAIK you can't customize construction of variant - it's just a move of given value into a new object (`Result` in this case). Function is some custom code which may have any number of arguments, side effects, and return an object of completely different origin than the given arguments. In terms of a question "if `Ok()` would be a function, what would really change?" - probably nothing, but still useful to understand what is what

Comment: The magic is that `expression()` returns some value that has `?` operator, `expression()?` calls this operator which is "expanded" by compiler to code with `return Err(...);` if `expression()` failed (without ever reaching `Ok(...)` construction). And if `expression()` succeeded, the value is successfully unwrapped by `?`, and this value is used by `Ok(...)`, which is then returned by your function `f`

Comment: I believe enum constructors actually are functions, or at least they implement Fn trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` operator either returns (as in the `return` statement) the error variant, or extracts the value from the `Ok` variant. Thus `Ok(expression()?)` is more or less equal to:

```
// This pattern is so common in rust, that the language designers
// introduced the `?` to reduce the amount of boilerplate needed
let result = expression();
let r = match result{
    Err(e) => return Err(e.into()), // tries to convert the error into the required type if necessary (and if possible)
    Ok(r) => r
}

Ok(r)
```

So basically `Ok(expression()?)` can be simplified to just
`expression()` if its `Err` variant matches the one from the function definition.

##### Historical context:

Extracting the `Ok()` variant and propagating the `Err` variant is a very common pattern in rust. In order to reduce the amount of boilerplate code, the rust team introduced the [try!()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try.html) macro; But it's so clumsy and does not really work well with method chaining. The rust team introduced the `?` operator, which is doing absolutely the same thing, except for it's not so intrusive as `try!()`

Comment: But this return on line 3 would not make sense if it were within the body of `Ok`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: This code from Svetlin is somewhat "inserted" in place of `Ok(expression()?)` by compiler, rather than being a body of `Ok(...)`. You see `?` has a special privilege to return from your function in case of error without proceeding further. It's not clear how compiler achieves this, "inserting" of this code is one of logical possibilities

Comment: @vasily The `match` on a  `Result` is so common in rust, that the language developers introduced the `?` operator to reduce the boilerplate needed. It's just a syntactic sugar, which the compiler understands and expands to something like the code above.

Answer (score -1):

`?` just leverages the error returned by `expression` if it exists or unwraps the value from within the returned `Ok` if not. `Ok(expression()?)` could be just `expresion()` and clippy would warn you about that:

```
warning: question mark operator is useless here
 --> src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     Ok(expression()?)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try: `expression()`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(clippy::needless_question_mark)]` on by default
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#needless_question_mark
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a719b9034834a4b387e84c823d168671)

You can follow the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) for further information

As per the comments. Notice that `?` is useful if the error types differ but you have an implementation of `From` between error types or you use `Box<dyn Error>` as return type.
In which case you can either, bubble up the error if it is an error, otherwise rewrap the value with an `Ok`

```rust
Ok(expression()?)
```

or, map your error type into the correct error type with [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err)

```rust
expression.map_err(|e| ...)
```

Comment: The `?` might be useful (if not necessary) [if the error types differ](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=196ab62768d972c1efb5bf3ef13f2977). Though I like [`.map_err(From::from)`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b89bbae7121d9a70c07569034df46f1f), I'm not sure everybody does.

Comment: @Masklinn, but that is just if you have the from implementation from one error to the other right? (commonly used in `thiserror` crate for example)

Comment: correct, but that works out of the box if you're returning `Box<dyn Error>`. Clippy does seem to handle this case correctly and only warn if the error types are the same though, which is nice.

Comment: @Masklinn, yes, if you use the trait would work too.